# "How couldn't I do" vs. "how couldn't I have done" in the sense of criticiizing oneself for failure to do something in the past

Tags: modal-verbs, could-modal

Could you tell me if I have to use *how couldn't I* or *how couldn't have I* in the sense of criticizing oneself for failure to do something in the past? For example:

> The problem turns out to be so easy. **How couldn't I figure it out**/**how couldn't have I figured it out**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither "how couldn't I" nor "How couldn't have I" are standard, common phrases for this situation, or indeed for any situation I can think of. I suspect that are actually grammatically incorrect. The concept could be expressed as:

- > How could i have failed to figure it out.
- > Why didn't I figure it out.
- > I don't understand why I didn't figure it out.
- > Surely anyone could have figured it out, but I didn't.

There are many other possible and correct variants on this theme.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem turns out to be so easy. **How couldn't I figure it out/how couldn't have I figured it out.**

I would say both of your suggestions are wrong. The correct one would be:

> The problem turns out to be so easy. How couldn't I have figured it out?

Also,

> The problem turns out to be so easy. Why couldn't I have figured it out?